# How to automatically start tmux on SSH session?

Tags: ssh, tmux

I have ten or so servers that I connect to with SSH on a regular basis. Each has an entry in my local computer's `~/.ssh/config` file.

To avoid losing control of my running process when my Internet connection inevitably drops, I always work inside a `tmux` session. I would like a way to have tmux automatically connect every time an SSH connection is started, so I don't have to always type `tmux attach || tmux new` after I SSH in.

Unfortunately this isn't turning out to be as simple as I originally hoped.

- I don't want to add any commands to the `~/.bashrc` on the servers because I only want it for SSH sessions, not local sessions, and I would prefer to only set it up once.
- Adding `tmux attach || tmux new` to the `~/.ssh/rc` on the servers simply results in the error `not a terminal` being thrown after connection, even when the `RequestTTY force` option is added to the line for that server in my local SSH config file.

Comment: have you considered accepting one of the higher-voted answers instead of the currently accepted one? A lot has changed since 2014 :)

Comment: @Sixtyfive thanks for the prompt, just reviewed the current set of answers. I think the accepted answer is still the simplest solution to the exact need I described in my question, but I'm glad that so many people are finding useful information about related needs in this thread! Your answer in particular is very thorough – just gave it an upvote. 

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Alright, I found a mostly satisfactory solution. In my local `~/.bashrc`, I wrote a function:

```
function ssh () {/usr/bin/ssh -t "$@" "tmux attach || tmux new";}
```

which basically overwrites the ssh terminal function to call the built-in ssh program with the given arguments, followed by `"tmux attach || tmux new"`.

(The `$@` denotes all arguments provided on the command line, so `ssh -p 123 user@hostname` will be expanded to `ssh -t -p 123 user@hostname "tmux attach || tmux new"`)

(The `-t` argument is equivalent to `RequestTTY Force` and is necessary for the tmux command.)

Comment: If your version of `tmux` supports it, consider using `tmux new -A foo` which will attach to an existing session named `foo` if possible, creating it if necessary. This lets you simplify your function to `/usr/bin/ssh -t "$@" tmux new -A` (and be sure to quote `$@`!).

Comment: Note: if some of the machines you connect to regularly don't have tmux installed, you might want to say `function ssht` or the like so that you can continue to use `ssh` normally. Otherwise, just type `/usr/bin/ssh` at the command prompt whenever connecting to a machine without tmux :)

Comment: If you are lazy, you can just use [ssht](https://github.com/brejoc/ssht) to connect to you remote tmux sessions.  
OS X users can [tap it via brew](https://github.com/brejoc/homebrew-tap) and Linux users can create a package via [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki) with this [Makefile](https://github.com/brejoc/ssht/blob/master/Makefile) or simply copy `ssht` to `~/bin`.

Comment: Haha nice! Seems like a bit of overkill to me to wrap this bash one-liner in a whole Github repo with Makefiles and brew and such but hey, the easier the better!

Comment: Same solution for ZSH would be: `ssh(){ /usr/bin/ssh -t $@ "tmux attach || tmux new";}`

Comment: I find that connecting via `ssh user@hostname` and running `tmux attach || tmux new` separately works fine. However `ssh -t user@hostname "tmux attach || tmux new"` renders characters like 'ä', 'ü', 'ö', etc as '_'. Both environments have `$LANG=en_AU.UTF-8`, `TERM=screen`.

Comment: Solved: `ssh -t user@hostname "LANG=$LANG tmux attach || tmux new"`

Comment: Since unfortunately not all my target environments have tmux installed, I adapted it to `function ssh () { /usr/bin/ssh -t $@ "tmux attach 2>/dev/null || tmux new 2>/dev/null || bash"; }` This way it silently falls back to a good old fashioned bash login.

Comment: How do you handle Suspension using `Ctrl+A` Ctrl+Z`? For me the ssh session goes into comatose.

Comment: perfect ! And if you want to just drop to classic ssh you can do so with `$(which ssh) user@host`. 

of course, backticks can be used instead of `$(...)`, but I cannot write them here due to code formatting

Comment: The alias can be simplified to `ssh -t "$@" tmux new -As session`

Answer (score 134):

### Server-side configuration:

To automatically start tmux on your remote server when ordinarily logging in via SSH (and only SSH), edit the `~/.bashrc` of your user or root (or both) on the remote server accordingly:

```
if [[ $- =~ i ]] && [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && [[ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]]; then
  tmux attach-session -t ssh_tmux || tmux new-session -s ssh_tmux
fi
```

This command creates a tmux session called `ssh_tmux` if none exists, or reattaches to a already existing session with that name. In case your connection dropped or when you forgot a session weeks ago, every SSH login automatically brings you back to the tmux-ssh session you left behind.

### Connect from your client:

Nothing special, just `ssh user@hostname`.

### What if I mess up and lock myself out somehow?

Just skip the init file with `--norc` when you connect:

```
$ ssh -t myname@myserver bash --norc
```

(You might also need `--noprofile`, depending on your setup)

Or just connect with `sh`:

```
$ ssh -t myname@myserver sh
```

Then fix your mistake and try again.

Comment: I was looking for this, also I used a piece of code very similiar to yours some time ago, but the session was the username (changing `ssh_tmux` to `$USER`)

Comment: This is much better than accepted. Because I am using msys2, by altering client side ssh,  connect to remote would not aware the change of TERM , which result to powerline theme render ugly .  Tmux session can be separated by $USER is another good point.

Comment: See moneytoo’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819740/2948889) for useful comment on `$SSH_TTY` vs `$SSH_CONNECTION` too.

Comment: Should be `~/.bashrc` just fyi (it's a minor 1-character typo, so SO won't let me edit)

Comment: you can use `tmux new-session -A -s ssh_tmux` to replace `tmux attach-session -t ssh_tmux || tmux new-session -s ssh_tmux` much shorter, if a bit more confusing, `-A` tells tmux to attach the session if it already exists

Comment: To avoid breaking "scp", you'd also need to check if this is an interactive shell: `if [[ -n "$PS1" ]] && [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && [[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]]; `

Comment: @janfrode don't rely on `$PS1`, use `[[ $- == *i* ]]` instead, as PS1 may be defined even when it's not an interactive shell.

Comment: Can I write this into `.zshrc` as well?

Comment: Can you please add some more explanation to your bash code. It is hard to read if someone don't understand bash. I see three if conditions. Why?

Answer (score 101):

## Don't do this on the server-side!

That is potentially dangerous because you can end up being locked-out (see † below) of the remote machine. Also, no shell hacks / aliases / etc. are required to achieve this - SSH already knows how to do it.

## Instead...

... make use of (your client's) `~/.ssh/config` like so:

### tmux 3.1 or newer¹ on the remote machine

Into your local `~/.ssh/config`, put²:

```
Host myhost
  Hostname host
  User user
  RequestTTY yes 
  RemoteCommand tmux new -A -s foobar
```

- As pointed out by @thiagowfx, this has the side effect of making it impossible to use, e.g. `ssh myhost ls /tmp` and should therefore not be used with `Host *` ... what I like to do is to have a `Host myhost` section *with* `RemoteCommand tmux ...` and then in addition to that I'll have a `Host MYHOST` section *without* it.
- Instead of `RequestTTY yes` you could call `ssh` with the `-t` switch; thank you, @kyb.
- Off-topic, but if you're dealing with non-ASCII characters, I'd recommend to change that into `tmux -u …` for explicitly enabling Unicode support even on machines that don't have the proper environment variables set.

### tmux 3.0a or older on the remote machine

Almost the same as above, but change the last line to³:

```
  RemoteCommand tmux at -t foobar || tmux new -s foobar
```

---

¹ [repology.org](https://repology.org/project/tmux/versions) has a list of distros and their tmux versions

² `new` is short for `new-session`.

³ `at` is short for `attach-session`.

---

Only if, for some reason, you really, really can't do it client-side:

### Using the remote's `authorized_keys` file

If you would rather not have an `~/.ssh/config` file for whatever reason, or want the remote machine to force the connecting machine to connect to / open the session, add this to your remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
command="tmux at -t foobar || tmux new -s foobar" pubkey user@client
```

This will, of course, work from *all* clients having the corresponding private key installed, which some might consider an upside –– ***but***: should anything go wrong, it might not be possible to connect anymore without (semi-)physical access to the machine!

## One caveat!

As @thiagowfx notes in the comments, this should not be put underneath `Host *` as it breaks certain things, such as `git push`. What I personally do is to add a second entry in all-uppercase letters for where I want to automatically be connected to tmux.

---

*† I've gotten lucky with using https://serverfault.com/a/201158 to get back into a remote machine that had been prepared as shown in kingmeffisto's answer.*

Comment: why `tmux at` instead of `tmux a`? Also it would be wise to use a named session for this or tmux would attach to "random" existing sessions upon loging into the host.

Comment: How do you suspend the tmux session? ssh goes into kindda limbo state after hitting `Ctrl+A` `Ctrl+Z`.

Comment: It just disconnects. As far as I'm concerned, that's the behaviour I would expect and am happy with.

Comment: Nope it stays there, Ctrl+C doesn't work, Ctrl+Z doesn't work either, ssh needs to be killed. Having to open another terminal to kill ssh every time I disconnect tmux remotely is not satisfactory. How do you manage ssh not to get into a comatose state upon disconnecting the remote tmux session?

Comment: I use that setup (now with your improvements) on a daily basis, connecting and disconnecting dozens of times per day. All I can tell you is that `Ctrl B-D`, after detaching from the tmux session, also causes the connection to the host to be closed and me being back at a local shell...

Comment: `Ctrl-B` `D` works treat compared to `Ctrl-B` `Ctrl-Z`. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @Eric, I had skipped the `Z` in `Ctrl-Z` ... that wouldn't work, yeah. Happy you have it working now! :-)

Comment: This should be, imho, the most voted answer. I was looking exactly for (2).

Comment: This says to me: `open terminal failed: not a terminal`, solved with `ssh -t`, forcing pseudo-terminal

Comment: @kyb, that's the command line switch equivalent to `RequestTTY yes` ... was the latter present in your `~/.ssh/config` entry?

Comment: @Sixtyfive, yeah I missed it

Comment: This works well with standalone servers, however when used with `Host *` unfortunately it makes `git push` (with ssh) stop working: `Cannot execute command-line and remote command. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: @Sixtyfive Can you elaborate on why this is "dangerous"? (by potentially editing your answer)

Comment: You can lock yourself out of the remote machine. I'll try to work it into the answer. Happy for suggestions on how to best do that...

Comment: Eric, `tmux at` and `tmux  a` are the same - they're both short for `tmux attach`. In fact, `tmux att`, `tmux atta` and even `tmux attac` all work as well :-)

Comment: It is worth noting that `~/.ssh/.config` is on the client side, that is the computer you use to login to the server. I kept wondering why this did not work while I was editing `~/.ssh/config` on the server.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks Albert, I changed it to disambiguate that. Also added a paragraph about what you commented on, @thiagowfx, as that's the one big caveat with this method.

Answer (score 33):

**Connect:**

```
ssh user@host -t "tmux new-session -s user || tmux attach-session -t user"
```

**During session:**

Use `Ctrl+d` to **finish session** (tmux window closes) or `Ctrl+b d` to **temporary detach** from session and connect to it again later.

> **Remember!** If your server restarted session lost!

When you are inside tmux anytime you can use `Ctrl+b s` to see **sessions list** and switch current to another.

**Fix your .bashrc:**

I recommend you to define universal function in your `.bashrc`:

```
function tmux-connect {
    TERM=xterm-256color ssh -p ${3:-22} $1@$2 -t "tmux new-session -s $1 || tmux attach-session -t $1"
}
```

It uses `22` port by default. Define your fast-connect aliases too:

```
alias office-server='tmux-connect $USER 192.168.1.123'
alias cloud-server='tmux-connect root my.remote.vps.server.com 49281'
```

**Login without password:**

And if you don't want to type password everytime than generate `.ssh` keys to **login automatically**:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Put your public key to the remote host:

```
ssh-copy-id -p <port> user@hostname
```

**Additional tips:**

If you want to use **temporary session-id** which corresponds with a local bash session use as **tmux** id:

```
SID=$USER-$BASHPID
ssh user@host -t "tmux new-session -s $SID || tmux attach-session -t $SID"
```

Comment: A neat trick to avoid that `||` in some use-cases is to include `new-session` in `.tmux.conf` and just always use `tmux a -t 0`.

Comment: In newer versions of tmux you can also use `tmux new-session -A` which will attach if it exists otherwise it will create a new one.

Answer (score 19):

I used lines from @kingmeffisto (I'm not allowed to comment that answer) and I added an exit so terminating tmux also terminates the ssh connection. This however broke SFTP sessions so I had to check for `$SSH_TTY` instead of `$SSH_CONNECTION`.

EDIT 4/2018: Added test for interactive terminal via `[[ $- =~ i ]]` to allow tools like Ansible to work.

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ] && [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ] && [[ $- =~ i ]]; then
    tmux attach-session -t ssh || tmux new-session -s ssh
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 15):

As described in [this blog post](http://jordanelver.co.uk/blog/2010/11/27/automatically-attaching-to-a-tmux-session-via-ssh/) you can ssh and then attach to an existing tmux session with a single command:

```
ssh hostname -t tmux attach -t 0
```

Comment: That's what my answer does (although I use `tmux attach || tmux new` so that a new tmux session isn't created for every connection). 
The tricky part is that the correct command is `ssh -t user@host tmux attach || tmux new` and the only way to alias something that needs an argument inside the command string is to create a new function, like I did above.

Comment: I know, but some people (like me) might prefer a one-liner that doesn't involve defining a function

Comment: This connects to a session called '0'. That is, the general form is `ssh [hostname] -t tmux attach -t [sessionName]`

Comment: This worked really well for me.. Combined this will https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116674.. so now my putty GUI looks like this.. http://imgur.com/uFhxN30. I can disconnect the sessions with Cntrl + b + d. Very simple and convenient..

Answer (score 4):

I have the following solution that gives you two SSH hosts to connect to: one with tmux, one without:

```
# Common rule that 1) copies your tmux.conf 2) runs tmux on the remote host
Host *-tmux
    LocalCommand scp %d/.tmux.conf %r@%n:/home/%r/
    RemoteCommand tmux new -As %r
    RequestTTY yes
    PermitLocalCommand yes

# Just connect.
# Notice the asterisk: makes possible to re-use connection parameters
Host example.com*
    HostName example.com
    User login

# Connect with tmux
Host example.com-tmux
    HostKeyAlias dev.dignio.com
```

Comment: This is great! 

Note to other fans of this solution: You do not need to add the third host block at all (`Host example.com-tmux`) if you have no use for a HostKeyAlias (or other customization) for your tmux variants and if you do not care for shell autocompletion (I use aliases anyway). If you call `ssh example.com` only the second block will match and if you call `ssh example.com-tmux` both will match. That way you have to define only one Host block for each of your servers and can update your old configs by just adding the `*-tmux` block and appending asterisks to your existing entries

Answer (score 3):

This is the one that actually creates a great user-experience.
It automatically starts tmux whenever you open the terminal (both physically and ssh).
You can start your work on one device, exit the terminal, and resume on the other one. If it detects someone already attached to the session it will create new session.
Put it **on the server**, depending on your shell `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`.

```sh
 if [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] ;then
     ID="$( tmux ls | grep -vm1 attached | cut -d: -f1 )" # get the id of a deattached session
     if [[ -z "$ID" ]] ;then # if not available attach to a new one
         tmux new-session
     else
         tmux attach-session -t "$ID" # if available attach to it
     fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

[byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) is a nice useful wrapper for tmux/screen. Connects to an existing session if present or creates a new one.

I use it with [autossh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) which gracefully reconnects the ssh session. Highly recommended in case of intermittent connectivity issues.

```
function ssh-tmux(){
  if ! command -v autossh &> /dev/null; then echo "Install autossh"; fi
  autossh -M 0 $* -t 'byobu || {echo "Install byobu-tmux on server..."} && bash'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find this useful - uses ssh in a loop and reconnects to or connects to an existing tmux session so you have a nice easy reliable
way to reconnect after a network outage

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# reconnect to or spawn a new tmux session on the remote host via ssh.
# If the network connection is lost, ssh will reconnect after a small
# delay.
#

SSH_HOSTNAME=$1
TMUX_NAME=$2
PORT=$3

if [[ "$PORT" != "" ]]
then
    PORT="-p $PORT"
fi

if [ "$TMUX_NAME" = "" ]
then
    SSH_UNIQUE_ID_FILE="/tmp/.ssh-UNIQUE_ID.$LOGNAME"

    if [ -f $SSH_UNIQUE_ID_FILE ]
    then
        TMUX_NAME=`cat $SSH_UNIQUE_ID_FILE`
        TMUX_NAME=`expr $TMUX_NAME + $RANDOM % 100`
    else
        TMUX_NAME=`expr $RANDOM % 1024`
    fi

    echo $TMUX_NAME > $SSH_UNIQUE_ID_FILE

    TMUX_NAME="id$TMUX_NAME"
fi

echo Connecting to tmux $TMUX_NAME on hostname $SSH_HOSTNAME

SLEEP=0
while true; do

    ssh $PORT -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -Y -X -C -t -o BatchMode=yes $SSH_HOSTNAME "tmux attach-session -t $TMUX_NAME || tmux -2 -u new-session -s $TMUX_NAME"
    SLEEP=10
    if [ $SLEEP -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo Reconnecting to session $TMUX_NAME on hostname $SSH_HOSTNAME in $SLEEP seconds
        sleep $SLEEP
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm reviving an old thread but I've done some work on the bashrc solution and I think it has some use:

```
#attach to the next available tmux session that's not currently occupied
if [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && [ "SSH_CONNECTION" != "" ];
then
    for i in `seq 0 10`; do #max of 10 sessions - don't want an infinite loop until we know this works
            SESH=`tmux list-clients -t "$USER-$i-tmux" 2>/dev/null` #send errors to /dev/null - if the session doesn't exist it will throw an error, but we don't care
            if [ -z "$SESH" ] #if there's no clients currently connected to this session
            then
                tmux attach-session -t "$USER-$i-tmux" || tmux new-session -s "$USER-$i-tmux" #attach to it
                break #found one and using it, don't keep looping (this will actually run after tmux exits AFAICT)
            fi #otherwise, increment session counter and keep going
    done

fi
```

There's a cap at 10 (11) sessions for now - I didn't want to kill my server with an infinite loop in bashrc. It seems to work pretty reliably, other than the error of tmux failing on list-clients if the session doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thie way allows you to reconnect to an old tmux instance if your ssh session drops. The `exec` saves a fork of course.

```
if [ -z "$TMUX"  ]; then
  pid=$(tmux ls | grep -vm1 "(attached)" | cut -d: -f1)
  if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
    tmux new -d -s $pid
  fi

  exec tmux attach -t $pid
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**Append to bottom of your remote server's `~/.bashrc`**,  *(or possibly its `/etc/.bashrc.shared` (1))*:

```
# ======================== PUT THIS LAST IN .BASHRC ==========================
# --- If we're run by SSH, then auto start `tmux` and possibly re-attach user.
#       $-         interactive only via current option flags
#       -z $TMUX   no tmux nesting
#       $SSH_TTY   SSH must be running, and in a shell
#
if [[ $- == *i* ]] && [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && [[ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]];  then
  tmux attach-session -t "$USER"  || tmux new-session -s "$USER" && exit
fi
```

---

**Many good tips above combined here**, e.g. **`$-`** and **`$SSH_TTY`** are better I think.

And I like adding a few comments to help this old guy remember what's going on without having to look it up.

And finally, I like an **`exit`** at the end to cleanly come home when I'm done.

**Thanks everyone.**

---

***Note** I source a shared `/etc/.bashrc.shared` at the end of both user and root's `.bashrc`'s, for common stuff used in both, like colorized `ls`, various aliases, functions and path extensions, i.e. I don't want redundant code in my root/.bashrc nor user/.bashrc.*

Answer (score 0):

[This guys script works great](https://github.com/spencertipping/bashrc-tmux/blob/master/bashrc-tmux). Just copy the *bashrc-tmux* file to *~/.bashrc-tmux* and source it from *~/.bashrc* right after the PS1 check section.